# The discrete orthogonal polynomials

Tags: polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials, inner-product

I want a document or something that explains the following proposition:

> The discrete orthogonal polynomials are the polynomial solutions of the given diference equation:
> $$
> \sigma(x)\Delta\nabla  P_n(x) +\tau(x) \Delta P_n(x) + \lambda_nP_n (x) = 0,
> $$
> where $\Delta P_n(x) = P_n(x + 1) -P_n(x)$ and $\nabla  P_n(x) = P_n(x)-P_n(x-1)$ indicates backward fnite-diference operator and forward fnite diference operator, respectively. $\sigma (x)$ and $\tau (x)$ denote first and second degree functions. $\lambda_n$ indicate a suitable constant.

Comment: What is the proposition here? This looks rather as a definition.